# Proving thermodynamic identities in differential form

Tags: thermodynamics

I am looking for help with a question relating to thermodynamical identities in differential form.

Any help or hints are appreciated.

I have included my progress so far for reference:

$T$ denotes temperature, $V$ denotes Volume, $U$ is energy, $S$ is entropy and $p$ is pressure

**(1)** has been proven
$$(\frac{\partial U}{\partial p})_{T} = -p(\frac{\partial V}{\partial p})_{T} - T(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T})_{p}$$

from this I am looking to prove **(2)** below

$$(\frac{\partial U}{\partial p})_{T} = (\frac{\partial U}{\partial p})_{V}+(\frac{\partial U}{\partial V})_{p}(\frac{\partial V}{\partial p})_{T}$$

My inital process was to use the first relation and insert equivalent values for $-p$ and $-T$

Taking the general differential form of the first law of thermodynmaics to find values of $-p$ and $T$

$$(\frac{\partial U}{\partial V})_{p} = T(\frac{\partial S}{\partial V})_{p} - p(\frac{\partial V}{\partial V})_{p}$$

Rearranging this gives the following value:

$$-p = (\frac{\partial U}{\partial V})_{p} - T(\frac{\partial S}{\partial V})_{p}$$

and

$$T = (\frac{\partial U}{\partial S})_{V}$$

Inputting this into **(1)** I obtain the following

$$(\frac{\partial U}{\partial p})_{T} = ( (\frac{\partial U}{\partial V})_{p} - T(\frac{\partial S}{\partial V})_{p}
)(\frac{\partial U}{\partial p})_{T})- T(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T})_{p}$$

This gives the following:

$$(\frac{\partial U}{\partial p})_{T} =  -T(\frac{\partial S}{\partial V})_{p}(\frac{\partial V}{\partial p})_{T} - T(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T})_{P} + (\frac{\partial U}{\partial V})_{p}(\frac{\partial V}{\partial p})_{T}$$

The final term is as required so the next thing is to prove that:

$$T(\frac{\partial S}{\partial V})_{p}(\frac{\partial V}{\partial p})_{T} - T(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T})_{P} = (\frac{\partial U}{\partial p})_{V}$$

I can't seem to figure this out:

I tried inputting the value for $T$ but that doesn't appear to help

Perhaps there is a way to reduce

$$T(\frac{\partial S}{\partial V})_{p}(\frac{\partial V}{\partial p})_{T} - T(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T})_{P} = T(\frac{\partial S}{\partial p})_{V}$$

where:

$$T(\frac{\partial S}{\partial p})_{V} = (\frac{\partial U}{\partial p})_{V}$$

Comment: Your first equation is incorrect

Comment: Where is Eqn 2?

Comment: I edited Eqn 1. This doesn't effect the calculations shown below. Eqn 2 is $(\frac{\partial U}{\partial p})_{T} = (\frac{\partial U}{\partial p})_{V}+(\frac{\partial U}{\partial V})_{p}(\frac{\partial V}{\partial p})_{T}$

Comment: What is dU(P,V) in terms of dP and dV?

Comment: Is this what you're referring to? $dU=TdS-pdV$ I am confused by your question

Comment: No.  I meant the purely mathematical relationship $$dU=\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial P}\right)_VdP+\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial V}\right)_PdV$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a hint.
Write differentials of $ U(P,V)$ and  $ V(P,T)$.
Substitute differential of $ V(P,T)$   in differential of
$ U(P,V)$. 
Then compare it with differential of $ U(P,T)$.

Comment: Thanks! Just solved it using your hint.

Comment: You can solve it in 3 lines if you notice differential of U and your final answer.